# Any alternative to create real consecutive numbers in MySQL, immune to ROLLBACK?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, auto-increment, rollback

I am building a system that requires to store certain records with a consecutive number. At this point AUTO INCREMENT works just fine, until there is need for ROLLBACKS: After such consecutive record exists, I have to perform some processes using that consecutive number and that process may Fail, which leads to an inevitable ROLLBACK...

The next time I try to insert a record, the AUTO INCREMENT column can not use the already lost consecutive number due to certain "unbreakable" rules from MySQL.

I can not use the `MAX(id) + 1` way, because there may be another user in the system doing the same process, generating his/her own/next consecutive id with success.

I have an idea about this: To get all consecutive IDs so far in that table, and loop them with the program to find the first missing ID, although I'm not sure about this because another user may be doing the same (and there could be only 1 missing consecutive, so both users will try to insert using the same consecutive.... etc, etc.).

So, I need this consecutive to be consistent even if there is need of ROLLBACK.

**Is there any alternative to AUTO INCREMENT (in MySQL, with PHP, or anything else), so that I can generate consecutive IDs in a consistent way no matter if I have to ROLLBACK one or two of those insertions?**.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The only way to do that is to lock the whole table for write so there was only one writer at any particular moment. It's a terrible solution actually, but since you didn't explain the **real task** (and in fact asked a typical XY-problem question) - then there is no way to suggest a better solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no declarative way to do what you want.  You have to write procedural code.

> I can not use the MAX(id) + 1 way

Yes, you can. To start with, you have to write code that either

- locks the table, or
- tries again when the dbms returns a duplicate key error.

There are tradeoffs in each approach, but both can maintain an unbroken sequence of numbers even when there are rollbacks.

But that's not the whole story. You also have to prevent changes from breaking the sequence.  So you *must* either revoke update and delete privileges on that table, or you must prevent updating or deleting an existing id number in some other way.

> To get all consecutive IDs so far in that table, and loop them with
>   the program to find the first missing ID,

If you already *have* a broken sequence, you'd better fix that first.